# FindInstance for all real values satisfying a condition

Tags: mathematical-optimization, algebraic-manipulation, inequalities

I seek at least one instance of positive fractions $p,q,r$ where $p,q,r \in \mathbb{Q}^+$, for which
$$\frac12 (a - 2 b + c)^2 \ge pa^2 + qb^2 + rc^2\quad \forall\ a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}.$$
I used this code

```
FindInstance[{1/2 (a - 2 b + c)^2 >= 
    p*a^2 + q*b^2 + r*c^2 && {p, q, r} ∈ 
    Rationals && {a, b, c} ∈ Reals }, {p, q, r}]
```

But it simply returns the code to me, with an error that the system contains independent variables $a,b,c$.

Next, I replaced **FindInstance** with **Reduce** and I got many solutions with conditions on $a,b,c$. I would like to restrict them to the values of $p,q,r$ that work $\forall\ a,b,c$. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following shows that [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce) thinks there is no answer:

```
Reduce[
    ForAll[
        {a,b,c},
        {a,b,c} ∈ Reals,
        1/2 (a-2 b+c)^2>=p*a^2+q*b^2+r*c^2
    ] && p>0 && q>0 && r>0,
    {p,q,r}
]
```

> False

Comment: Thank you! I will edit this further to try out my other hypotheses.

Comment: @Carl: What does `False` mean in this context?

Comment: @Tugrul Based on my various "experiments" (a, b and c are vector norms), I think False means the expression **cannot** be reduced under the given constraints.